# Invalid Date error after packaging an electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I have wrote an application with Electron, Everything works in development env.

But after the `electron-packager` I have Invalid Date ...

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

[...]

render() {
    const { code } = this.props;

    moment.locale('fr');

    return (
        <div className="ViewCode">
            <header>
                { code.code }
                <span style={{flex: 1}}></span>
                <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                <i className="fa fa-trash" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}></i>
            </header>
            <article>
                <div>Name { code.code }</div>
                <div>Expiration Date { moment(code.expirationDate).format('LLLL') }</div>
                <div>Max use { code.maxUse }</div>
                <div>Max use by user { code.maxUseByUser }</div>
                <div>Action { code.action }</div>
                <div>Number of use { code.users.length }</div>
            </article>
        </div>
    )

}

}
```

Before packaging : `jeudi 31 décembre 2015 00:59`

After packaging : `Invalid Date`

Any idea?

Comment: It could be that one needed package is installed under devDependencies. Look inside your package.json file and check your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `code.expirationDate` is not a date object, you might check its lifecycle. Or just display something else if there is no valid date:

```
render() {

    const { code } = this.props;

    moment.locale('fr');

    if(!code.expirationDate instanceof Date) {

        return <div>something</div>;

    } else {

        return (
            <div className="ViewCode">
                <header>
                    { code.code }
                    <span style={{flex: 1}}></span>
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                    <i className="fa fa-trash" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}></i>
                </header>
                <article>
                    <div>Name { code.code }</div>
                    <div>Expiration Date { moment(code.expirationDate).format('LLLL') }</div>
                    <div>Max use { code.maxUse }</div>
                    <div>Max use by user { code.maxUseByUser }</div>
                    <div>Action { code.action }</div>
                    <div>Number of use { code.users.length }</div>
                </article>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to use `BrowserWindow.openDevTools()` and `console.log` to help you debug these kind of bugs.

Comment: Your answer does not clear, why the date formatting works before packing in the test enviroment.

Comment: Well, without seeing where `code.expirationDate` is instancied, I can't tell, the only thing I'm sure is it's not defined. Then, why, that could be antwhere in your data lifecycle, maybe could you provide some other piece of codes ?